# std::map not insert on empty?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Today I just notice empty_map[key] will create an null element in the map. I was not expecting that. Is there a map like container where i'll just get null and not create an element? I suppose there isn't and need to replace all my [] with .find()

Comment: How would you "get a null"? The semantics is that `operator[]` returns by reference.

Comment: Look at `at()` rather than `find()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at

Comment: @juanchopanza: The same way map[invalid_key] creates an element and sticks it in the map ;)

Comment: but it returns by reference, so there is no meaningful way of doing that without inserting an element. The concept of null isn't clear for values either. You can't distinguish a default initialized value from some "null" value.

Comment: @juanchopanza: good point. I still dont like the idea of adding elements on reads.

Comment: @acidzombie24: If you want to enforce that elements aren't added, try using `const` references to `std::map` instances.  Then you have no choice but to use `find` (or `at`).

Comment: While `at` is tempting using an exception to handle your control flow here seems clumsy. I would rather stick with `find`. I would like to see a performance comparison of the two though.

Comment: @pmr: yep. I'm expecting many false finds bc i am traveling up a tree searching for a key. So exceptions isnt a good idea. Also i'd need to handle it where i call the function. Never a few method back (which is an exception plus, the i dont need to use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stuck with find().  That's just how `map` is designed, and there's no similar container with that behaviour as the only difference.  (Or as BoBTFish said, you can use `at`)

To elaborate a bit more, you can't have a reference to a NULL value.  This means you can you either have an iterator that points to the element or end(), or you can have a method that either returns a reference or throws an exception.  `find()` and `at()` are those two options.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like it, you could make your own container that delegates to `std::map` but provides a different, `const` implementation of `operator[]`.  Of course, be aware that the whole point of `operator[]` returning a reference is so that:

```
std::map<Key, Value> theMap;
theMap[someKey] = someValue;
```

can work.  Otherwise you'd be forced to do:

```
theMap.insert(std::make_pair(someKey, someValue)];
```

which seems like worse tradeoff than using `find`/`at` for lookups. (Or you could make `operator[]` return an iterator to the found item, but then that would be exactly the same as using `find`.)

Comment: oh right, i forgot `[]=` is a read/write and not simply a write. I guess i am spoiled by C# indexers. +1 for reminding me and that explaination